# What is Dynamic Hash finders and/or Hash Finder in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

If anybuddy know about what is **Dynamic Hash finders** and/or **Hash Finder** in Rails?

Are both the same terms?

Please give an example so I could get this properly.It seems bit confusing to me!

Comment: What would be its application? Where you find these terms?

Comment: One of my senior asked me to use dynamic hash finder or Hash finder...for my one of application for a rails module?

Comment: i just know the term 'dynamic finders' where you have `find_by_xyz_and_zyx` etc.

Comment: Why don't you ask your "senior" what he means? Also, you should make an attempt to understand why you are being asked to do something.

Comment: I am getting tested Mark.Well, Will this link help to get the answer. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2404 :(

Comment: Perhaps @ror_master is an inappropriate username if you're still confused about dynamic hash finders!  Just kidding.. In all seriousness though, I'm guessing that he must be referring to [dynamic finders with hash attributes for creation like this page references](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/3/14/dynamic-finders-with-hash-attributes-for-creation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic finders are what rails generates for your models based on the database fields.  Eg if your User model has an email field, then rails generates this method for the User class:

```
def find_by_email(s)
  ...
```

That's all that is.

A "hash finder" (i assume) means when you call .find, and pass a hash as the conditions:

```
User.find(:first, :conditions => {:email => "kev@foo.foo"})
```

These are two different things.  I don't know what a "dynamic hash finder" is.  I think you should get over your fear of your senior and ask him what he means.  Nothing wrong with asking for clarification, ever.  Better than going off and wasting time chasing ghosts.